# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo?

Tags: java

I am using the code below and I am trying to add a button to turn off wifi but I am getting the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
```

Any Ideas? Does the button code need to be placed somewhere else? 
Thanks!

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. 
 * @return */       

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);       
    TextView status = new TextView(this);                  

    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();  
    wc.SSID = "\"MyNetwork\""; //IMP! This should be in Quotes!! 

    wc.hiddenSSID = true; 
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;      
    wc.priority = 10; 
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK); 
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);  
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA); 
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN); 
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED); 
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP); 
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP); 
    wc.preSharedKey = "\"Password""; 
    WifiManager  wifiManag = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE); 
    boolean res1 = wifiManag.setWifiEnabled(true); 
    int res = wifi.addNetwork(checkPreviousConfiguration(wc)); 
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res ); 
    boolean es = wifi.saveConfiguration(); 
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "saveConfiguration returned " + es ); 
    boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);    
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );   

    tv.setText("You are now connected!  " +
            "Version 1.1");

    status.setText("The was an error connecting, please try again.");

       //@Override

    try {            
        Thread.sleep(5000);

         ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 

         if (connec != null && (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)){  
                //You are connected, do something online. 
                setContentView(tv);

            }else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ) {              
                //Not connected.         
               setContentView(status);
            }  

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Button OffWifi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.offwifi);
    OffWifi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
      public void onClick(View v) {                 
          WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);          
          }        
      });                       
}

public WifiConfiguration checkPreviousConfiguration(WifiConfiguration wc) {

    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();     

    for(WifiConfiguration config : configs) {         
        if(config.SSID.equals(wc.SSID)) return config;     
        }     
    return wc; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: NM needed  setContentView(R.layout.main); before the button